# How to retrieve build job status (success/error) for using in post-build steps?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In my build job on Jenkins, I have to make some post-build steps which depend on the build status. If the job was successful then do 'this'. Otherwise do 'that'.

How can I retrieve the build job status, using Groovy or whatever, and save it e.g. in an environment variable for using it in the post-build steps?

Answer (score 1):

Use  "Flexible publish" https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin as post build action

- In "Conditional action" "run?" choose "current build status" and define worst and best status
- add required action/actions which will be executed when condition is true!